# click a button in vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I was able to create my vba code to login to a password protected website but now i'm stuck on how to be able to automate the click through to where I need to extract my data. I'm not able to share the website but here is the line of html that I'm trying to click. It's a "Reports" button but I cant

This is the html code that I would like to click the button

```
    <a href="gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753" 
     class="menuitem">Reports</a>
```

This is the code for the website and login/password and click to login which is working flawlessly up to this point, next step is to click reports and extract the data through web query in excel. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub daily()
'
' daily Macro
'

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

    '  website
    MYURL = ""
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    ' user login and password
    HTMLDoc.all.user_login.Value = ***
    HTMLDoc.all.user_password.Value = ***
    For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagName("input")
    'click submit to login
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next

 'gives debug error***   If MyHTML_Element.Type = "Reports" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next


Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If


End Sub
```

Requested html of the site I am trying to click, I want the macro to click the reports button.

Trader Home | 
Transaction | 
Reports

New code that wont work when I press F5 but will work if I press F8 through the code:

Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Delmarva_daily()
'
' Delmarva_daily Macro
'

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

```
' website
MYURL = ***
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
' user login and password
HTMLDoc.all.user_login.Value = ***
HTMLDoc.all.user_password.Value = ***
' click submit
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagName("input")

If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
' click reports
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("menuitem")(1).Click
While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
'click Billing Analysis Report (Industrial)
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("firstlink")(0).Click
While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagName("input")

If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
```

Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If

End Sub

Comment: You have two `Next` and only one `For Each`.  Also those one-liner `If`'s may not be doing what you expect.

Comment: @Qharr how am I suppose to post the html when the character limit wont allow me too?

Comment: @ Qharr I'm receiving an error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the ctrl +k keyboard shortcut. ? I'm not sure what to do here when I copy and paste the HTML

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QGVIdeJ  here is the html code, I'm trying to click the "reports" button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reports button:**

You can try the following CSS selector to target the element of interest:

```
HTLMDoc.querySelector("a[href='gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753']").Click
```

Or the more traditional element by classname selection:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("menuitem")(1).Click
```

Or by tag (if there are indeed only 2 `a` tags!)

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).Click
```

---

**The CSS selector:**

```
a[href='gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753']
```

is looking for an element with an `a` tag having attribute `href` whose value is 
`gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753`.

---

**CSS query on your HTML sample:**

[image: query]

---

**Submit button:**

For the rest of your code: You can use the following to avoid a loop when clicking the input button depending on how many submit input buttons you have.

```
HTLMDoc.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click
```

You may also be able to use

```
HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit
```

---

### **After each Click|Submit:**

You want `While myBrowser.Busy Or myBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend` after each click|submit event, to allow time for page events to occur; and to reduce the chances of object not found due to trying to select an element before it is available on the page.

Comment: This worked to allow me to click the next button thanks! "HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("menuitem")(1).Click" but now I have 3 links to go to the next page and they are the same "class" name

Comment: please disregard my previous message. - I'm still having an issue, when I press F8 (Step into ) and go line by line through the code, I can get to where I want to go, but when I press F5 (Run/Continue) The browser that opens at the report click doesn't continue. I tried to save the code but still nothing. Let me include the updated code

Comment: So the button is clicked but there are problems with the extract data part?

Comment: Sorry QHarr, Let me try to be more specific. The button "reports" isn't clicked when I click F5 (Run Sub/userform), I thought testing by pressing F8 through the code would be useful as it works this way but when I click F5 the macro stops at the reports click page. I've included my updated code. Any reason for the difference? so for example, the code stops after HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit when I click f5, it doesn't continue compiling the rest of the code.

Comment: Comment out any error handling e.g. On Error .... and is there an error reported? Usually if F8 works but not F8 it is a timing issue and you need a wait somewhere.

Comment: I took out the on error code and now it works when I click F5 now.

Comment: Try putting a wait before the click then .... Application.Wait Now + Timerserial(0,0,5)   '<== reduce the time in seconds from 5 if works.

Comment: I'd be happy to click accept, as this question is now answered.(where is the accept button) I do have another issue but will open a new question for that

Answer (score 2):

```
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
```

is the same as

```
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then 
    MyHTML_Element.Click
End If
Exit For
```

...which is probably not what you wanted to do

"Reports" doesn't seem like a valid element type, so maybe you should post some of your HTML.